# Access BB Properties via bbUI

Tags: java, javascript, blackberry

is there any code example for this;

When user pressed a button or any field/view that created with bbUI, application do open Settigs Menu.

My point is, how could access the Java Object from js function in bbUI ? With scriptable? if so how?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try ? Can you add more details ?

Comment: I could not try any thing. Because i just begin learning today and i could not find any example code for my question. All examples about crating UI elements and change these element's properties. According to my searching, developers can control the phone (bluethoot, vibration, maps etc)with Java Objects. I am curious about how can access the the Java Objects via bbUI elements.

Answer (score 2):

BBUI is a user interface library so it doesn't provide any mechanism for accessing objects in the underlying OS the way I think you want to do. The WebWorks framework will provide the hooks I think you want. Beware that the WebWorks SDK comes in different flavours: BB10, PlayBook and Java-based smartphones. You may want to start here: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/#smartphones